# Solr MoreLikeThisHandler vs Disjunctive OR queries

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a use case in which I have certain terms (phrases rather) which I need to use to get matching documents from solr.

Should I use disjunctive OR queries ?

e.g.  q=text:("barack obama" "usa" "president"....)

OR

Should I use more like this handler ?

I have about 50 terms in the query. My index size is about 4 GB in total and I am on Win 7 64 bit with 8 cores and 8 GB RAM.

Performance with disjunctive OR queries have not been great so far (about ~1 sec per query).

Answer (score 0):

MoreLikeThis of Lucene is designed to find similar documents for a document you have. In your case you have terms/phrases where you want to find best matching documents. So MoreLikeThis is not an option. You need to perform an OR-query.

Comment: Well, I am getting these terms from a document itself. So, instead of getting these terms if I submit the document directly to MoreLiekThis, will it give better results ? and will it be faster than OR queries ?

Comment: When you only use term queries it should not be faster. But an experiment will show more accurate results. The quality of the resulting docs may be better because MoreLikeThis incorporates more information like the term frequency. If you have specific requirements where the phrases you get play an important role, then you might be better creating a custom solution.